# data duplicates while upload muiltiple image

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, upload

I'm having trouble while saving into database. It keep on insert duplicates data when i upload. May I know how can I prevent it ? There are no error in my codes below.

asp.net

```
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

vb.net

```
  Try
        If Me.FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName = "" Then
            Throw New Exception("Please  Attach file!")
        Else

            For Each postedfile As HttpPostedFile In FileUpload.PostedFiles

                fileName = Me.lblId2.Text & "_" & Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
                FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs((Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/UploadFile_/") + fileName))
                FilePath = "~/Attachment/UploadFile_/" + fileName
                filesize = Convert.ToInt32(fileName.Length)

                params.Clear()
                strsql = " INSERT INTO tb_upload " & _
                         " (UploadDT, cr_runnum,DestFileName,DataSize, FileName, Remarks) VALUES " & _
                         " (@UploadDT, @cr_runnum, @DestFileName, @DataSize, @FileName, @Remarks)"

                params.Add("@UploadDT", Format(datetimenow, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
                params.Add("@cr_runnum", Me.lblId2.Text.Trim)
                params.Add("@DestFileName", FilePath)
                params.Add("@DataSize", filesize)
                params.Add("@FileName", fileName)
                params.Add("@Remarks", Me.txtRemarks.Text)

                iResult = Common.execNonQuery(strsql, Common.txn, params)

                If iResult = 0 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Data insertion failed. Please contact MIS Administrator!")
                End If

            Next


        lblUnsuccess.Text = String.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", FileUpload.PostedFiles.Count)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.lblUnsuccess.Text = ex.Message
    Finally
        Common.CloseConn()
    End Try
```

function exec non query
[refer here exec non query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdqmW.jpg)

Comment: filesize = Convert.ToInt32(fileName.Length) this will not give you the size of the file. it will only give the length of the filename.

Comment: I allow user to upload multiple image, it keep on saving the 1st image selected but db have duplicate record with 1st image.

Comment: Your problem is not here. Show me your exec non query function

Comment: Please refer to the image.

Comment: It was working fine with other insertion codes. it only happen on this file upload.

Comment: I have tried this tutorial, it not success too: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-save-insert-multiple-files-to-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: i create it become class and link it to the vb.net.  Dim Common As New cMaster

Comment: When i select 1 image upload, it was working prefect.

Comment: I have upload it on the top of the codes."refer here exec non query"

Comment: it repeated the first records only. the second records is not save., however, i have clear the parameters.   params.Clear()

Comment: copy your code to notepad and try my updated code.

Comment: May I know where is your codes ? i cant find it anywhere. i have hide myself the filesize. it still not working and save duplicates record.

Comment: [Don't post images of code!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) Code in images cannot be debugged, rewritten or properly inspected! If you want help you **must** always post the code as text.

Comment: in your For Each postedfile As HttpPostedFile In FileUpload.PostedFiles. you are using fileupload.postedfiles inside your for each block. you should be using PostedFile instead. So when you have 2 attachment you are still trying to take the file information of the first file when at the second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using postedFile as your loop variable but then each time through the loop, you're using `FileUpload.PostedFile` instead of `postedFile`.  FileUpload.PostedFile is sort of a shortcut that gives you the first element of PostedFiles.

[image]

Also, as user7452368  mentioned in the comments, fileName.Length is the length of the fileName string, not the size of the file.  Here's [somebody else's question about how to get the file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583688/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-net-using-a-static-method).